# How to prevent the user to write anything but English Ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have an iOS app and I want to prevent the user from entering anything other than English characters in a textfield.

If not, is there a way I can convert the non-English characters into English characters.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you edit the code for swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restrict UITextField to English only? (Stopping Chinese pinyin input)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961910/how-do-i-restrict-uitextfield-to-english-only-stopping-chinese-pinyin-input)

Comment: There are many, many examples of how to allow only certain characters into a text field. Please do some basic research first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like this answer has been addressed in this previous post:

[How do I restrict UITextField to English only? (Stopping Chinese pinyin input)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961910/how-do-i-restrict-uitextfield-to-english-only-stopping-chinese-pinyin-input)

Wherein the suggestion is made, by user k_ppes, to use the following code:

```
tf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.ASCIICapable
```

Comment: Mark/Flag the question as duplicate rather than juste copy/pasting another answer.

Comment: Thanks.  New to actually posting here...don't know how to do that.  Will look into it

Comment: @DevinVyain in  50 seconds :P

Comment: FYI - at the time that I answered this question, my rep was 1.  I did not yet have the privilege to flag the answer as duplicate, which is granted at rep 15.  However, from now on, I will use this method.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Simply setting the `keyboardType` does not prevent a user from entering other text. A user can still paste anything into the text field despite the keyboard.